# Mysql Full text search along with group by is slow

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the following indexes:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`msg_id`),
KEY `ix_msg_user_id` (`msg_user_id`),
FULLTEXT KEY `ix_msg_text` (`text`)
```

If I just do a normal full-text search, it is fast and uses the full-text index:

```
SELECT * FROM msg WHERE MATCH (msg_text) AGAINST ("some text" IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

And the explain on that query is:

```
+----+-------------+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table  | type     | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | tweets | fulltext | ix_msg_text    | ix_msg_text    | 0       | NULL |    1 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+------+-------------+
```

Now, if I do the same query, but add a group by to it, it takes a very very long time:

```
SELECT max(created_at) FROM msg WHERE MATCH (msg_text) AGAINST ("some text" IN BOOLEAN MODE) group by msg_user_id;
```

The explain on that query is:

```
 +----+-------------+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
 | id | select_type | table  | type     | possible_keys  | key            | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                        |
 +----+-------------+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
 |  1 | SIMPLE      | tweets | fulltext | ix_msg_text    |   ix_msg_text | 0       | NULL |    1 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
 +----+-------------+--------+----------+----------------+----------------+---------+------+------+----------------------------------------------+
```

I've tried adding another index that encompasses both the text and the user_id like this:

```
ALTER TABLE ADD FULLTEXT INDEX `msg_msg_user_id` (`msg_text`, `msg_user_id`);
ERROR 1283 (HY000): Column 'msg_user_id' cannot be part of FULLTEXT index
```

But, it won't let me because msg_user_id is an int and can't be a part of a full-text index.  What is the best way to speed this query up?

Comment: Grouping by without any aggregate function doesnt make sense.

Comment: @Mihai yes, my bad, this is a simplified example of my problem, in the real query I have a max, will edit the question

Comment: Can you put the text search in the `HAVING` clause. It doesn't make much sense, but would it speed it up to do the search after grouping?

Comment: Aim for loose index scan, in your example query you need a composed index on (msg_user_id,created_at)

Comment: @dan08 moving it to the HAVING clause is fast, but then it would only be searching some of the text, the query needs to find all of the messages that have the text, and then group by the user_id